# FPS value is not understood as either a decimal or integer value in VideoWriter method

Tags: python, video-capture, opencv

So, currently, I am trying to extract an original video file, append the name of the file to create a new one, operate on each frame of the original, and write each frame to the new video.

I have isolated the error. it is in here
newVid = cv2.VideoWriter(output,-1, 30.0, (newW, newH))

When I run this line with 30 frames per second, python (on the Spyder 4.1 IDE) says 30 is a tuple, and not a real number. When I run it with 30.0, it says it expects an integer, not a float.

For now, ignore the operations on the original image, it's just a template object detection that works the way I need it to. This is the only error I am getting in the wider script.

```
# importing libraries 
import cv2 
import numpy as np 

# Create a VideoCapture object and read from input file 
path = r'C:\Users\BeckerLab\Downloads\20200314165554.MTS'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path) 

point = path.find('.')

def insert_dash(path, point):
    return path[:point] + '_processed' + path[point:]

newH = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
newW = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)

output = insert_dash(path, point)

newVid = cv2.VideoWriter(output,-1, 30.0, (newW, newH))

cap.release() 
newVid.release()
# Closes all the frames 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

kernal results

```
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\BeckerLab\almost.py", line 20, in <module>
    newVid = cv2.VideoWriter(output,-1, 30.0, (newW, newH))

TypeError: integer argument expected, got float


runfile('C:/Users/BeckerLab/almost.py', wdir='C:/Users/BeckerLab')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\BeckerLab\almost.py", line 20, in <module>
    newVid = cv2.VideoWriter(output,-1, 30, (newW, newH))

TypeError: must be real number, not tuple
```

Comment: That is also my thought: the first error is because the 3rd argument, frame rate, must be an integer.  The final error appears to refer to the tuple at the end.  However, the cv2 documentation I find clearly calls for a (H, W) tuple.  It's possible that OP is using a much older or much newer version of CV2 (different from the docs I found).

Comment: I've tracked docs from CV2 versions 2.4 to 3.10 -- they all specify `Size` for that argument, which a `tuple` should fulfill.  I'm perplexed.  All I can explain is the simpler fact that `30.0` is not a valid frame rate: the method signature requires an integer.